# Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

Ran full software update using software updater in 13.04.

When I ran software updater again, it is showing system is fully updated and no option is displayed for upgrading to 13.10.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that normal upgrade notifications may have been disabled.
Please check Softwares & Sources > Updates > Notify me of a new ubuntu version
Select 'For any new version'.
If it still doesn't work try this from the command line:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

If this doesn't work either, you can post the output of the command for further looking into.

Comment: All the notification update settings are correctly selected.So I typed in the command line.After checking for new ubuntu release, "no new release found " is displayed.

Comment: Can you try with sudo do-release-upgrade -d?

Comment: Yeah, I typed in.it is not working.Command not found.